# Excel - Macro to Find Numbers in a Column not in ascending order

Tags: vba, excel

In researching I found a formula that examines a whole column and answers true of false.    But its not what I need to accomplish.

I would like to Choose a Column of Numbers  and run a Macro that stops when a number is NOT Larger than then number that proceeds it.

I have a Column of 55000 supposedly in order numbers in ascending order.  I need to pick out errors in the ascension.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use this function to return all not sorted cells addresses:

```
Option Explicit

Function IsItSorted(rng As Range) As Variant
    Dim vals As Variant
    Dim nErrs As Long, iVal As Long

    vals = Application.Transpose(rng.Value)
    ReDim errs(LBound(vals) To UBound(vals)) As String

    For iVal = LBound(vals) To UBound(vals) - 1
        If vals(iVal) > vals(iVal + 1) Then
            nErrs = nErrs + 1
            errs(LBound(vals) - 1 + nErrs) = rng(LBound(vals) - 1 + iVal).address
        End If
    Next
    If nErrs > 0 Then
        ReDim Preserve errs(LBound(vals) To LBound(vals) - 1 + nErrs) As String
        IsItSorted = "Errors at: " & Join(errs, ",")
    Else
        IsItSorted = "Sorting: OK"
    End If
End Function
```

to be used in your main code as:

```
Sub main()
    MsgBox IsItSorted(Range("B2:B11"))
End Sub
```

Comment: This will work for me -- Thank  you so much  - I envy your knowledge.  It has pointed out several other things I must fix in my workbook in order to run the whole column as intended.

Comment: You are welcome. And don't envy me: we're all on our way to learn something more!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with an array formula. If your column is "A" and has 55000 rows, enter this array formula in any cell:

```
=AND(A1:A54999 <= A2:A55000)
```

It's an array formula, type it and press `Ctrl+Shift+Enter`. It **wont work** if you just press `Enter` like a normal formula.

**EDIT**

So the problem is not only to know whether there is an error, but to spot it. Here's a VBA macro that will `Select` the first occurrence of the sorting error, otherwise it informs you of no error. It uses the current selected cell as the first cell in the column to check.

```
Sub checkColumnSorting() ' <-- uses current selection as first cell in column
    Dim firstCell As Range, lastCell As Range, i As Long, ar
    Set firstCell = Selection
    With firstCell.Parent
        Set lastCell = .Cells(.Rows.Count, firstCell.Column).End(xlUp)
        ar = Application.Transpose(.Range(firstCell, lastCell))
        For i = LBound(ar) To UBound(ar) - 1
            If ar(i) > ar(i + 1) Then
                .Activate
                .Cells(i + firstCell.Row, firstCell.Column).Select
                msgBox "Error in ascending sorting at row " & i + firstCell.Row
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Next
    End With
    msgBox "Ascending sorting is Ok"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you  - My Result tells me false -- indicating an errant number but where ?  My Hope is for something that will stop going through the column at the error spots.  I figured there must be an error at some point but the search through 55000 rows is the issue I then face and hope to find a solution to point out the error cells.

Comment: @Mstuf I added a VBA macro to spot the error and take you there immediately. Please see the edit.

Comment: I do apologize for not thinking of all the variables -  Can you edit this to run from the active cell ?  I have some cells at the beginning of the sheet with Letters in front of them that this version will not make it past.     Sorry for my lack of knowledge and forethought about that,

Comment: @Mstuf ok so the new (edited) version is a macro that will check the sorting starting from the selected cell and downward.